# Extra bracket error, europasscv + biblatex

Tags: biblatex, europasscv

Am trying to use `europasscv` and `biblatex` with the publications split into categories, but get an error.

```
pdflatex <file>
[...]
! Argument of \end has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.23 \printbibtabular[title=A,category=aa]
```

Here is the Latex file:

```
\documentclass[swedish,a4paper,10pt]{europasscv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=ynt,style=numeric,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{europasscv-bibliography}

\addbibresource{mwe}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{aa}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bb}

\begin{document}

\begin{europasscv}

\addtocategory{aa}{A:2019}
\addtocategory{bb}{B:2019}

\nocite{A:2019}
\nocite{B:2019}

\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}}

\printbibtabular[title=A,category=aa]
\printbibtabular[title=B,category=bb]

\end{europasscv}
\end{document}
```

and here is the `.bib` file:

```
@Book{A:2019,
  author =   {A},
  title =    {A},
  publisher =    {A},
  year =     {2019}
}
@Book{B:2019,
  author =   {B},
  title =    {B},
  publisher =    {B},
  year =     {2019}
}
```

**Edit**: how do I get it to run without errors **AND** produce nice output?

Comment: The redefinition of `\section` (`\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}}`) is faulty. If I remove it the example compiles fine.

Comment: @moewe: that messes up the format, as it puts bigger headings in normal font and black colour instead of the proper ones. I need to do something about the section commands that the bibliography prints.

Comment: I think `ecvitem` is the proper command to use at that point.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}{}}` it is still wrong, but might look more like what you have in mind. The problem with the initial definition was that `\ecvitem` has *two* mandatory arguments. With `\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}}` you only have it one argument and `\ecvitem` would just go on and swallow whatever followed it as its second argument. Understandably, that does not always go well and so you got an error.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, I'm not really sure how it should look, as the cite keys are on the left of the dividing line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the  [`europasscv` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv/europasscv.pdf) `\ecvitem` takes one optional and two mandatory arguments.

> `\ecvitem[vspace]{left}{right}`

With the redefinition

```
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}}
```

`\section{#1}{#2}` will be replaced with `\ecvitem{#2}` and so `\ecvitem` is missing its second argument. It will just go on and gobble whatever comes next as its second argument. Understandably, that can not always go well. (Note that the `\section{#1}{#2}` here is a bit misleading. Since `biblatex` uses `\section*` as default heading, the `#1` will actually just be the `*`. So we actually replace `\section*{#2}` with `\ecvitem{#2}`. Naturally this would come out wrong if one were to use `\section{Title}` or even worse `\section[Short]{Long}`.)

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want, but you could try

```
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}{}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}{#2}}
```

I'm not too happy about this since this redefinition does not really reflect normal usage of the command `\section` in most document classes (where you could have `\section*{Unnumbered}` or `\section[Short]{Long}`), but it will work without error for this use case.

Note the `defernumbers` option.

```
\documentclass[swedish,a4paper,10pt]{europasscv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric, sorting=ynt, defernumbers, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{europasscv-bibliography}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{aa}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bb}

\begin{document}

\begin{europasscv}

\addtocategory{aa}{sigfridsson}
\addtocategory{bb}{nussbaum}

\nocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}

\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\ecvitem{#2}{}}
\printbibtabular[title=A,category=aa]
\printbibtabular[title=B,category=bb]

\end{europasscv}
\end{document}
```

[image: CV]